# How do I load a SVG file that's been generated with PHP?

Tags: php, apache, svg, xampp

I want to create a SVG file with PHP, and then include it in a HTML file.  Here's what I have so far (following [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/37004/0/page/1))

**svg.php:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/
REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg width="310" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g style="stroke:black;fill:lightgreen" transform="translate(30,30)">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="30" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <circle cx="170" cy="25" r="20" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <line x1="265" y1="10" x2="200" y2="70" style="stroke-width:4"/>
        <text x="80" y="90" style="font:size: 8">Basic shapes</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html,body, #MOSVG { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <object data="svg.php" type="image/svg+xml" id="MOSVG" />

</body>
</html>
```

When I look at `index.html` all I see is a blank page.  There's no warnings/errors on the console.  Apache error logs (I'm using XAMPP) give `[Mon Jul 09 14:36:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/svgtest/public/svg.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/svgtest/public/`.  They're in the same directory.

Comment: Found/fixed already, still getting the issue.

Comment: if you remove the <?xml?> line it renders the svg

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Why it's set up to break in the tutorial is beyond me....

Comment: Check whether [short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is enabled in php.ini, it's known to cause weird problems with xml output - also see the workaround presented in the referred doc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GeoPhoenix answered above, I figured I'd put it into an answer so that there's an offical one:

> if you remove the `<?xml?>` line it renders the svg

PHP can see `<?` as the opening tag for PHP code (rather than an XML declaration), thanks to the [short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting ([thanks to fvu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401500/how-do-i-load-a-svg-file-thats-been-generated-with-php#comment15034606_11401500)).  This is an easy fix, I just replaced

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

with

```js
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';?>
```

This has the same intended result and doesn't cause syntax errors.