# PHP post page being rendered in plain text - content type conflict

Tags: php

Good morning,

I have an issue with the rendering of my file output, it seems to show it as plain text which you can see at this link if you try typing and submitting it.

[www.hiven.net/index.php](http://www.hiven.net)

It seems as if the page is being rendered as plain text, but the only explanation I can see online is if I had set it to be plain text in my php header, which I haven't. Is it because I am setting the output content type to PNG, and if so, how can I make it render the image on a HTML page?

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  process();
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function process()
{
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $_POST["name"]);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your link seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Jimmy Working fine

Comment: You are still outputting your HTML code before the image, which is of course wrong.

Comment: You are telling the browser that (first) you're giving it a HTML type document, and then you're giving it a PNG type document. This document can not be both types at the same time. Display one or the other. Not both.

Comment: @Martin I thought that was the issue, but I don't want my entire page to be a PNG type, just the image that is generated. I'm not sure how to isolate the type to just the image.

Comment: @BizzyBob It's not my end, perhaps because im on IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Martin I thought that was the issue, but I don't want my entire page to be a PNG type, just the image that is generated. I'm not sure how to isolate the type to just the image.

This **IS** the issue, you're telling the browser that your page (whatever.php) is a HTML file *and then* you're telling it that it's a PNG file. This is obviously incorrect as a file can not provide headers to be multiple types at the same time.

What is happening is this:

- Server sends HTML data with headers stating something link `Content-type: text/html`
- Server sends [static] HTML contents (which you display).
- Server *then* sends the output of PHP `process()` function which is:
- Header for PNG stating `Content-type: image/png`
- Data contents for PNG file.

Can you see how this causes a clear issue that the browser is loading one output rather than another.

## Solutions

- 1) Just output the PNG, this will involve *not* sending HTML headers or HTML content ([credit to User2342558](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42416259/3536236)).

  ```
  <?php
  require_once('functions.php');
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      process();
      exit;
  }
  <html>
  ...
  ```

Note the `exit;` which forces PHP to stop executing the page once the `process` function is done, so that once the PNG is output then no further output is provided to the browser. This means the browser will only see one file type contents and will not present an error.

> but I don't want my entire page to be a PNG type,

You state you don't want the page to be just a PNG image, so another solution is here:

- 2) Load the PNG as a seperate `<img>` file

**pngfile.php**

```
   require_once 'functions.php';  // Requires and includes do not need brackets.
   $inputData = urldecode($_GET['data']);
   process($inputData);
   exit;
```

**whatever.php**

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $data = $_POST['name']; // the data from the form input.
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
         <img src="pngfile.php?data=<?php print urlencode($data);?>"
              alt="png php file">
     </body>
     </html>
```

This will then reload the current page and pass the input form fields as URL values to the `pngfile.php` script which will run as if it is a PNG file, and nothing else.

This means your form page will load both the form and the image at the same time. And as these two files both have separate and distinct headers (one is `text/html`, the other is `image/png` this will not cause a browser problem.

- 3) A third and probably more complex solution is to construct the image as an `SVG` codeblock and display it inline in the HTML page, this negates the need to provide headers but there may be various [secondary issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11401500/3536236).

  This would also need a fair bit of code adjustment for you current functions.

**Finally**

As ever with PHP, also keep an eye on your [PHP error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file).

---

**Process function Editing**

You need to update the process function to accept and use the data value. your default process function is using script-global values (`$_POST`) but will need to use the values specified in `process($data)` part of your `whatever.php` because the image file (`pngfile.php`) will get nothing POSTed to it.

```
<?php
  function process($newData){  
  $image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $newData); //updated
        // To use the specified value passed into the function. 
  ... 
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  echo $image;
  exit; // should be return not exit here. 
}
?>
```

Comment: I followed solution 2 because it seems like a really tidy solution but I can't get it working. This is the complete code set: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d721ab56e20fb943f495d1d5e46a7ba and this is the link www.hiven.net/index2.php - it just seems to draw a blank image?

Comment: @Jimmy ok take a look I've exampled pssing the data to the `process` function.

Comment: Ah I see, so I would do ```function process($data)``` and ```$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $data);``` - That hasn't quite worked for me just yet but it gives me enough to investigate. Oh you have helped, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes that was just my fault copying in, it doesn't look like that on the server

Comment: @Jimmy if you're just copy pasting my answer, I've just seen that I had the wrong POST value, i had put `$_POST['text']` when the input *type* is text and it's name is *name*. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the code immediatly after require_once('functions.php');:

```
require_once('functions.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    process();
}
```

And then put a exit; after echo $image;:

```
echo $image;
exit;
```

That because the html code corrupts the source of the image you are trying to send to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put else condition for form display

```
<?php 
require_once('functions.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  process();

}
else{
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: and add `exit` too