# Is there a way to execute PHP code in a SVG Image?

Tags: php, svg, exploit

Even after hours of research I couldn't find any way to get php code executed through a svg image on an apache server running php.

Is it possible to execute php code in a svg image?

If yes, how?

UPDATE:
The function processing the file is:

```php
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc -> loadXML(file_get_contents($imageFile), LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_DTDLOAD); // $imageFile contains the .svg
$svg = $doc->getElementByTagName('svg');
echo $svg->item(0)->C14N();
```

Now I would like to execute custom PHP code that I wrote in the SVG and get the result displayed by `echo $svg->item(0)->C14N();`.

The PHP code must be executed on the back-end server that contains above function.

Comment: well the webserver needs to be told to let PHP handle the file to execute any code, otherwise its just a static asset. And since we have zero supporting information, yes it is possible.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11401500/9969672) is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your server to do so but that is not the best practice.

Add the forth line to httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-phps .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php3 .php3 .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .svg
```

The downside to this is every request for an .svg will take longer as it runs as a php. And that <?xml will need to be changed on every svg file since by default PHP wants to use <? as for shorthand ... not good.

Alternatively you can use .htaccess within a directory so when you call mysvg.svg it runs mysvg.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.svg$ $1.php [L]
```

But the best practice is to send the svg from a php. Example: [How do I load a SVG file that's been generated with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401500/how-do-i-load-a-svg-file-thats-been-generated-with-php) Why hide the fact that the SVG is being dynamically created by php?

---

Update: If you want to run some php code triggered by an SVG being rendered.

```
<svg width="200" height="200"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image href="http://example.com/pixel/" height="1" width="1"/>
</svg>
```

Note: http://example.com/pixel/index.php script delivers a png pixel and runs some code.